# Setting APP_DEBUG=false in Laravel causing Gateway timeout (504)

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-6, http-status-code-504

I have an application which process around 500 records, which is working fine when I set `APP_DEBUG=true`. But if I run the same application by setting `APP_DEBUG=false` it is causing `Gateway timeout` issue. I don't understand why the application is behaving like that. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Probably in the codebase (maybe service provider) there may be an if statement for connecting to a remote service when it set to "false" (such as database endpoint, cache etc)

Comment: @Ersoy No, I don't have any such connections.

Comment: I may suggest two things; Log the exception in app/Handler to trace exception - check for  error log of nginx/apache for further info.

Comment: @Ersoy I don't see any logs, but, this is happening after I upgrade Laravel from v5.5 to v6

Comment: are you getting timeout when you process 10, 50, 100 records ? Are these records stored in database ?

Comment: @Ersoy yes the records are stored in database and I'm paginating the result with 15 records per page.